# Do we need all these number-of-player tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have: [multi-player](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-player), [two-players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-players), [extra-players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extra-players), and [player-number](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-number).  These tags have 6-11 questions per at present.  Two of them have no wikis, and the wiki for multi-player says "more than two players", which is not the definition of "multi" I am familiar with.

What should we do with these tags?

Comment: I've posted my preferred approach as one answer.  Please post others and vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nuke them all.

They add nothing, in my opinion (besides opportunities for people to go tagging everything in sight).

For me, nearly any tag that groups multiple unrelated games together is probably a meta-tag, and we shouldn't use it.

Comment: How long is it appropriate to wait before acting?  (This seems the clear winner so far.)  And can we delete the tags wholesale without bumping all the questions, or will we have to do this in batches to not flood the main page?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - it should be cool to just blast through these during a lull.  Maybe Friday night?  We're still working the rules/strategy tags.

Comment: Ok, I'll find a lull and blow them away.  I've been trying to delete the rules tag when editing the post anyway; that and strategy are much bigger piles so bulk-editing won't work.

Comment: I think we should do something with the magic questions, as the tag there has a clear and useful meaning.  A magic specific tag would make sense.

Comment: I created mtg-multiplayer for the subset of multiplayer that were about MtG.

Answer (score 2):

I can only see one valid use for multi-player. That would be with [mtg](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg). The rules differ in some respects, and the answers differ too when offering advice about about a duel deck versus a multi-player deck. As for a tag, mtg-free-for-all would be better.

I suppose in most situations, the OP could/would specify the environment that the deck is being played in. We only have 3 or so mtg-ffa questions right now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should merge all of these into [player-number](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-number) and write a wiki for it.  This tag should almost always be accompanied by a game-specific tag.  (The exception there would be questions of the form "what games work well for seven players?".)

Nobody would ever search for extra-players without also searching for a specific game (what does it mean in isolation?), so searching for game + player-number works just as well.  All non-solitaire games are multi-player, so that tag isn't particularly meaningful.  As for two-player, why distinguish that if we don't distinguish one-player and other specific numbers of players?  What's special about two?

Comment: It seems that questions of the form "what games work well for seven players?" are [considered](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/276/recommendations-for-6-player-board-game) [off-topic](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-are-some-good-8-player-games). Not a criticism, but it makes it seem unlikely that the case "not accompanied by a game-specific tag" will occur with an on-topic questions.

Comment: @ErikP., thanks -- I remembered having seen questions like that, but didn't remember them being closed.  In that case yeah, I can't think of a case where a game-specific tag wouldn't apply.